# How to use maven deploy when there is no Tomcat Manager?

Tags: tomcat, maven, deployment, liferay

I am currently developing JSR-268 portlets and using Liferay as my portal. I have read all the maven tutorials and posts about using the Tomcat plugin to deploy to Tomcat via the manager application. Unfortunately I don't believe this works with Liferay as it takes over the ROOT application thus removing the Tomcat Manager application. I would like to know if there is a way to deploy my portlet application via the Liferay deploy folder. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you gone through this link http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/12322618 Make sure you change value of liferay.auto.deploy.dir in pom.xml to point to your auto deploy directory

Answer (score 2):

Liferay provides its own deployment manager. You can login as a Super Admin in Liferay and go to Plugin Installation in Control Panel.

This allows you to inject .war file for portlets, themes, layouts etc.

The plugin installer also shows the installed components. You can undeploy them runtime.

Please have a look at [Liferay Plugin Installer](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugin+Installation)

Comment: I am currently using this system to manually deploy the .war file everytime I do a build. Liferay also has a "deploy" folder where it continually scans and automatically deploys wars and other appropriate files. I would like maven to be able to copy the war to this folder or use some other automated mechanism so that the newly built war is automatically deployed. Thanks though.